# PHP user defined function not being called?

Tags: php, user-defined-functions

I have a webpage and I have a session_check file that is used to check the session variables. I added `require 'session_check.php'` at the top of the webpages where it is required. I have also used `echo` to check that the `session_check.php` file got called.

I have a function in session_check.php that gets called when it's time to log out, but it never gets called. Could you please help me out? Thanks :)

*Code for `session_check.php`*:

```
<?php
    //Database Connection 
    $db_host = $_SERVER['DB_HOST'];
    $db_uname = $_SERVER['DB_UNAME'];
    $db_pwd = $_SERVER['DB_PWD'];
    $db_name = $_SERVER['DB_DB'];

    $db_link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uname,$db_pwd);
    if(!$db_link){
        die("Could Not Connect:".mysql_error($db_link));
    }
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_link) or die('Can\'t use db:'. mysql_error($db_link));

    //Logout function
    function user_logout($uname){
        $query = "UPDATE user SET last_used_token='' WHERE username='$uname'";
        mysql_close($db_link);
        session_destroy();
        header('Location:index.php');
        exit(); 
    }

    //Getting session variables
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
    $cur_authkey = $_SESSION['authkey'];
    $uname = $_SESSION['username'];

    //Session data checking 

    $query = "SELECT last_used_token FROM user WHERE username='$uname'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db_link) or die('Error while updating auth key <br /> Query:'.$query.'MySQL error no:'.mysql_errno().'<br /> MySQL error:'.mysql_error($db_link));
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($cur_authkey != $row['last_used_token']){
        user_logout($uname);
    }   

?>
```

*Partial Code of the calling webpage*

```
<?php
    require 'session_check.php';
    mysql_close($db_link);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>.....</html>
```

Comment: Set the session_start() as the first line in the php code.

Comment: unrelated but you are exposed to SQL injection attacks unless you sanitize or parametrize your inputs

Comment: @OneManCrew That didn't work..

Comment: @Ozzy You mean use `mysql_escape_string($_SESSION['authkey']);` ?

Comment: I mean you haven't shown the code you are using to get the $uname from the user, however it is evident from your code that you are not using prepared statements. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: @Ozzy Thanks a ton :) Looking into it now :) Learning something new

Comment: The function called is in an `if` condition. Is the line before the condition ever called? Same question for the line after? Could you imagine what to put in an `else` clause following this if

Comment: @greg0ire Yes, the line before the if gets called, and also the line after, I have echoed it and checked. And I can't think of anything in else, because I am just going to be linking this to a bunch of files using `require`, the logout function needs to be called only in case of a mismatch, otherwise no action needs to be taken

Comment: Maybe you could do step by step debugging with XDebug to get a better idea of the actual execution path

Comment: DO NOT use mysql_* functions.  it will be removed soon.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the below code was working.refer these codes,you will get solution.if u want to call the second page from first page using require() method, just call, require(secondpage url) in first page and remove the line session_start() in the second page.

first page(samplephp.php)

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['host']="localhost";
$_SESSION['dbusername']="root";
$_SESSION['dbname']="userinfo";
$_SESSION['username']="testuser";
$_SESSION['authkey']="1";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body>test<form action="session_check.php"><input type="submit" value="click here"></form></body></html>
```

second page(session_check.php)

```
 <?php
    session_start(); 
        //Database Connection 
        $db_host = $_SESSION['host'];
        $db_uname =$_SESSION['dbusername'];
        $db_pwd = "";
        $db_name = $_SESSION['dbname'];

        $db_link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uname,$db_pwd);
        if(!$db_link){
            die("Could Not Connect:".mysql_error($db_link));
        }
        mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_link) or die('Can\'t use db:'. mysql_error($db_link));

        //Logout function
        function user_logout($uname,$db_link){
            $query = "UPDATE usertable SET flag=1 WHERE username='$uname'";
            mysql_query($query, $db_link);
            mysql_close($db_link);
           session_destroy();
           echo "success";
            //header('Location:index.php');
            exit(); 
        }

        //Getting session variables
        session_regenerate_id();
        $cur_authkey = $_SESSION['authkey'];
        $uname =$_SESSION['username'];
        //Session data checking 

        $query = "SELECT flag FROM usertable WHERE username='$uname'";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $db_link) or die('Error while updating auth key <br /> Query:'.$query.'MySQL error no:'.mysql_errno().'<br /> MySQL error:'.mysql_error($db_link));
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($cur_authkey != $row['flag']){
           user_logout($uname,$db_link);
        }    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `session_start()` at the start of the code just after first `<?php` tag

Comment: where did you use it. use this function it the top of the session_check.php file

Comment: Yup, I put it on the line right after `<?php`  and still it doesn't work